# Django: is it possible to validate and save fields of several forms in one generic view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models:

```
class Person( models.Model ):
  username = models.CharField
  name = models.CharField( max_length = 30 )
  surname = models.CharFields( max_length = 30 )
  ...

class PersonSkills( models.Model ):
  person = models.ForeignKey( Person )
  skill = models.CharField( max_length = 30 )
  ...
```

I would like to add data to Person and to PersonSkills in one view.

Now I have RegisterView like the next:

```
class RegisterForm( ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ( 'username', 'name', 'surname', 'password', )

class RegisterView( FormView ):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = "/welcome/"
    template_name = "register.tmpl"
    is_valid = True
    def form_valid( self, form ):       
        form.save()
        self.is_valid = True
        return super( RegisterView, self ).form_valid( form )
    def form_invalid( self, form ):
        self.is_valid = False       
        return super( RegisterView, self).form_invalid( form )
    ...
```

So how can I add data to Person and to PersonSkills in one view? Inheritance from FormView allows only one form_class.

Comment: One more thing to note. Why have you got a Person model? That's nearly exactly the same as the built in contrib.auth.models.User model. You should be using the User model where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of achieving what you want is to create a custom form that declares the fields required for both models. Use the `save` method of the form to save to the individual model classes, by accessing the fields within `cleaned_data`.

Then your FormView will work as expected. It'll be receiving inputs for two different models, but the logic is contained entirely within the form. As with all custom forms, put validation logic within the various `*clean*` methods.

Comment: Excuse me. Do you mean declaration form fields manually (not using snap to model) like this: name = forms.CharField( max_length = 30 )? In this case we need to care about the situation when username is not unique.

Comment: @serg that's absolutely what I mean. You can use the `clean_name` method of the form (provided the field is called name), to validate that particular field. Your question doesn't currently deal with uniqueness within the form or model, but it's easy to bake in. Look at using `unique=True` within the model field declaration as well, to prevent invalid data at the DB level, incase it slips through the application